# How to filter all EWS items by excluding those which match Id's from list

Tags: c#, exchange-server, ews-managed-api

I want to be able to apply a SearchFilter based off the Item Id when I find all items in a selection of folders.

I can easily get all items and then using linq apply a where clause like

```
(w => !uniqueItemIdList.Contains(w.Id.UniqueId))
```

But the issue is this would be after it's pulled 1000's of mail items instead of during the original find of the items.

My goal is to pull all emails copy them to a db then afterwards to only pull emails that I haven't already copied by excluding emails with matching unique ids.

So far everything indicates that this isn't possible and that I could only search on individual fields like FolderId = "..." or subject that contains "...", with no mention of a list or exclusion.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ItemId isn't a searchable property so what you trying to do with a SearchFilter won't work. SyncFolderItems https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563967(v=exchg.150).aspx does allow an exclusion list based on ItemId (but I would think for a large number of items this wont scale) an easier solution would be just use a SearchFilter based on Item Creation Date.